# Multiple AND operators in Firebird and Python

Tags: python, firebird, firebird2.5

This is example code of what I'm trying to do - to be able to search on user input on more than two input boxes and respectively in more than two database columns:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE col1 LIKE ? AND col2 LIKE ? AND col3 LIKE ?;""", (
"%" + self.col1.get() + "%",
"%" + self.col2.get() + "%", 
"%" + self.col3.get() + "%",))

records = cur.fetchall()
        # Fill TreeView
  print_records = ''
  for record in records:
    print_records += str(record) + "\n"
    self.tree.insert("", END, values=record)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

The problem is that this code works correctly until I add the `AND col3 LIKE ?` After that the shown results are not true. Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure that there are rows that match all 3 conditions?

Comment: Yes, every row is unique and the user should be able to search based upon entry in one of the boxes, whatever the user desides to search for.

Comment: Have you tried with only col3 and none of the other columns?

Comment: @mousetail Thank you for the answers.Yes I did. As a matter of fact querying each of them individually gives the results I'm after.

Comment: what EXACTLY do you mean by "this code works correctly" and not ??? Show sample data, sampel correct and sample incorrect output. USe TraceAPI (example: http://FBProfiler.sf.net  ) and show as EXACT verbatim query and params data as it comes to FB server

Comment: Should mean they give you DIFFERENT rows your three filters, and none of the rows fits all filters at once. Try SQL CTE: `with q AS ( SELECT IIF( col1 LIKE ?, 'yes', 'NO') as C_1, IIF(col2 LIKE ..... ) as c_3, * from table ) select * from q where (c_1 = 'yes') or (c_2 = 'yes') or (c_3 = 'yes')` and see

Comment: Please provide a [mre], including necessary DDL and sample data.

Comment: Well first things first. I know for sure that there are 3 records with same value in column1 and different values in the other two columns, checked in FlameRobin. [Here](https://pastebin.pl/view/4d381311) is the example code from the DB. It's strange that when the query is run in FlameRobin I'm able to all retrieve the records.

Comment: u may try here, though it is fb3 not fb2.5: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0 / try to fetch rsb$db_key column to see if rows are really same or not. Or do linear select with filtering turned into columns. fb2 does not support BOOLEAN type natively, thus IIF work-around

Comment: are you sure in python you have to run `execute` not some other method? it seems you do one-liner, procedure call kind, not a multi-line query. What should look like multi-row fetching in Python? there should be some loop, calling fetch-next-row method, by any name

Comment: do you even do fetching or not ? https://wiki.python.org/moin/DbApiCheatSheet

Comment: Yes I am, sorry about that, didn't copy the whole code. I edited the main question with it.

Comment: then see above about CTE and about TraceAPI. No one can debug your program but you. We merely can suggest debugging techniques we see promising, but it is up to you to try them and learn from them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got away with the problem like this: overall the search function has one of the columns to be filled in every search. So I made a few IF statements in python to read that box and based on the entry showing results with SQL queries:

```
values = [self.col1.get(), 
               self.col2.get(), 
               self.col3.get()]

        if values != '':
            if values[1] or values[0] != '':
                cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE ? AND col2 LIKE ?;""", ("%" + values[0] + "%", "%" + values[1] + "%", ))
            if values[2] != '':
                cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM table WHERE col3 LIKE ? AND col2 LIKE ?;""", ("%" + values[2] + "%", "%" + values[1] + "%", ))
        else:
            pass
```

The code works and shows the results me and the user is trying to fetch. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You must use OR in your query instead of AND if you want "user to be able to search based upon entry in **one** of the boxes". Current query is searching for entry in **all** boxes.

Comment: Unfortunately for me I do have to watch for **all** the boxes. I've tried with the OR operator with no luck so far. Thank you for your answer.